# C - How robust should the "compar" argument to fts_open be?

Tags: c, traversal

fts_open as defined [on the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html) takes a comparison function as an argument. While I understand it's good practice to put error checks into functions, what is actually expected of the function? Will FTS ever provide null values as arguments or does it check on its own for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTS will call your function with valid pointers only. That is, given:

```
int my_compar(const FTSENT **ppx, const FTSENT **ppy) { ... }
```

`ppx` will be valid, `*ppx` will be valid, `**ppx` will be valid (and the same applies to `ppy`).

The only caveat is that the `fts_accpath`, `fts_path` and `fts_pathlen` fields of the `**ppx` and `**ppy` `FTSENT`s must not be accessed.

---

About error checks in general: You can't check whether a pointer is valid. You can check for null pointers, but not for uninitialized values, pointers whose target no longer exists ("dangling"), etc. So the checks you can do are very limited anyway.

For function parameters it is the caller's responsibility to provide valid values. In this case the "caller" is `fts_open`. Its description only says "*[the `compar` function] takes two pointers to pointers to `FTSENT` structures as arguments*", meaning that is exactly what it will pass. If it had wanted you to handle null pointers (or pointers to null pointers), the documentation would have said so explicitly.